# Mass email customers for a password reset

Tags: customer, magento-1.9, password-recovery

We want to import our customer database from our old site to our new one which we are going to use cart2cart for but from other reviews on the internet I hear they do not transfer the customer passwords. Is there a way I can send a mass email to every customer asking them to go change their passwords, giving them a link to click on?

Comment: You can send an e-mail saying that the passwords are not valid and a link to the 'I forgot my password' page.

Comment: Just as @Marius said: A link to the password forgotten page would be the best.

Answer (score 2):

You can send an e-mail saying that the passwords are not valid and a link to the 'I forgot my password' page.